# A = 1 else 0 if B satisfy two conditions in ms sql server(azure data studio)

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, case

I am trying to get the distinguish column depending on another column's value.
I was trying to approach with CASE function but could not get exactly what I wanted.

Condition

1. if ColB has only 1 then online
2. if ColB has only 2 then offline
3. if ColB has both 1 and 2 then both
4. if ColB does not have 1 or 2 then none

| ColA | ColB |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| A | 1 |
| B | 1 |
| B | 1 |
| C | 3 |
| D | 2 |
| D | 2 |

The result should be like this

| ColA | distinguish |
| --- | --- |
| A | both |
| B | online |
| C | none |
| D | offline |

Thanks!

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Comment: What should the result be if ('C',1) is added to the table?

Comment: For future reference, please create a [mcve] when asking questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you just need conditional `COUNT`

```sql
SELECT
  t.ColA,
  CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN t.ColB = '1' THEN 1 END) > 0 THEN
    CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN t.ColB = '2' THEN 1 END) > 0 THEN
      'both'
    ELSE
      'online'
    END
  ELSE
    CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN t.ColB = '2' THEN 1 END) > 0 THEN
      'offline'
    ELSE
      'none'
    END
  END
FROM YourTable t
GROUP BY
  t.ColA;
```

Comment: What if the ColB is not a numeric value but a string? are there any other ways?

Comment: Just put the values in quotes, see edit

Comment: What is not correct about it? Possibly you need to define your conditions better: what happens if there are *other* values?

Comment: There is no '1' for C. I think that part is only mistake otherwise it seems working properly

Answer (score 1):

This is just another way to skin the same cat, using a conditional `COUNT(DISTINCT)` and a conditional `MAX()`:

```
SELECT
  ColA
, distinguish =
    CASE COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ColB IN ('1', '2') THEN ColB END)
      WHEN 0 THEN 'none'
      WHEN 2 THEN 'both'
      ELSE
        CASE MAX(CASE WHEN ColB IN ('1', '2') THEN ColB END)
          WHEN '1' THEN 'online'
          ELSE 'offline'
        END
    END
FROM
  dbo.YourTable
GROUP BY
  ColA
;
```